# C# Calling an action asynchronously

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, async-await

I have a form post which should call an action asynchronously.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> SaveW2Document(Models.DocumentData documentData)
{
    some code here
    var ID = await Task.Run<int>(() => somObject.SaveDocument(uploadDocument));
   //Code that uses ID
   if(ID == something){
       //Do something    
   }
}
```

However it gets called synchronously and my other actions do not execute until this action gets completed.Is it something else that I need to do?

Comment: How is it called synchronously?  Is something *awaiting* it?  (Note that the only async call being invoked in this code is being awaited, so the execution within this method is going to stop until that operation completes.  Which kind of makes sense, given that the very next line relies on the result of that call.)

Comment: The action should get called asynchronously. i.e the UI should be free for other stuff which is not currently happening.

Comment: Do you call this method like `await SaveW2Document()`?

Comment: Well, how is the UI calling it?  An asynchronous method by itself doesn't define the synchronization of how it's invoked.  The code which calls it does.  Since this is a web application, should I assume it's being called by way of an HTTP request?  You can use AJAX from the client-side code to perform the request asynchronously.  But HTTP in general isn't asynchronous, a request always waits for a response.  `async` in this context is generally meant to allow the web server to free up resources so *it* isn't waiting for a response (and can handle more concurrent requests), but the browser is.

Comment: It gets called on a form post as mentioned in the first line of the question

Comment: Add the code that calls `SaveW2Document`

Comment: I feel compelled to tell you that you should ask your teacher who, obviously, gave you this as homework? But alas, I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a form post which should call an action asynchronously.

I think you're misunderstanding what "asynchronous" means in this context.  Using `async` controller actions (or HTTP request handlers in general) means that the *web server* can invoke the operations asynchronously and not hold a thread in a wait state while the operation completes.  This allows the web server to handle more concurrent requests more effectively.

The browser, however, *is* waiting for the response.  The asynchronous nature of any given operation generally isn't defined by the operation itself, but by whatever invokes it.  (For example, note how within this operation there is another asynchronous operation being awaited.  If this code didn't await it, the behavior would be very different.  But the method being invoked wouldn't change between those two scenarios.)

This makes sense, though.  After all, what is the browser going to do if it doesn't wait for the response from the server?  Display a blank page?

You can make asynchronous calls to a web server from client-side code by way of using AJAX.  That would allow the page to invoke the server-side operation and listen for the response without blocking or changing the context of the page itself.  But if the whole page context is posting to the server and waiting to load a new page, it needs to *receive* that new page before it can display it.

Comment: Okay let me explain. An ajax call pulls up a form. I add document and some information and this form gets submitted by a @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveDocument", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "uploadFile" }))
{//Form code}
It then calls the action i wrote in my question.This process needs to happen in the background.I dont care about its response I just care about what happens in the action(entry in database).I handle the response on a later visit to this page.I cant use ajax because call will get lost on a page reload.The call needs to be independent of UI

Comment: @nnm: The statements `"I don't care about its response"` and `"I can't use AJAX"` are mutually exclusive in this case.  Without a response, *what would the page display*?  It would be blank.  When you perform a page-level request for a new page (either a GET or a POST), the browser *needs* to wait for that response *before* it can display what's in that response.  If you want the action to be "fire and forget" then you'd need to invoke it in the background.  In a web browser, that means AJAX.

Comment: the form disappears after submit. with a message on the UI "come back later to view" so no blank page.The other links are visible and accessible.What do you mean by invoke in the background? That is what I want to accomplish by an Async action.So if I do an ajax to call this action instead of form post will it work?

Comment: @nnm: And what produces the message "come back later to view"?  Is it, perhaps, the `ActionResult` returned from this method?  If the UI needs to display the result of this method, how would it do that without waiting for this method to complete?  With AJAX you would be able to invoke this without unloading the page context, so the UI can continue to function without waiting for a response.  However, the "come back later to view" message would still need to wait for a response because the UI doesn't know if the operation succeeded/failed until the operation completes.

Comment: The "come back later" message will be handled independent of the action with jquery. When the user visits the website later he will be able to see this added document

Comment: @nnm: If using AJAX then, yes, the message can be displayed independently from JavaScript code.  (However I would still recommend awaiting the response of the operation before displaying it.  It wouldn't make for a very good user experience to tell the user that the operation has succeeded if it doesn't actually end up succeeding.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69139/discussion-between-nnm-and-david).

Comment: I wanted this basically [SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]

Comment: @nnm: It's *very* unclear how session state has anything to do with the problem being described.  If it works for you, that's great.  But do be careful that you're actually solving a problem and not just hiding it behind another problem.

Comment: You can go through the link to gain some clarity how its related.I might not be the best at describing it properly I guess.Maybe that's what caused the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Well I might not have been able to ask the question correctly.But I found the solution to the problem that was occuring. MVC has a behaviour that blocks concurrent requests coming from the same session.I will either have to Disable Session or make it readonly for that controller. Refer [this](http://johnculviner.com/asp-net-concurrent-ajax-requests-and-session-state-blocking/) link.

So adding `[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]` to my controller helped.

Comment: Best practice is to have SessionState set to read-only wherever possible. You should try your best to only write to the session on user log in/out so that you can keep all your other controllers with a read-only session state.